# Кастомизация опроса Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс, битрикс24

Такой вопрос, есть возможность создания на сайте с битриксом  опроса.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Он будет выглядеть примерно как на картинке.
Собственно вопрос в том как преобразовать подобный опрос в виде слайдера. Чтобы поэтапно  выводились вопросы с вариантами ответами ,после чего перелистывался слайд и выводился новый вопрос.
Прошерстил Интернет не смог найти примеров решения подобных задач.
Надеюсь на любые наводки.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

У Вас оригинальная задача и хотите найти пример выполнения этой задачи? Не удивительно, что такого нет. Кому охото тратить кучу времени, чтобы показать, как сделать что-то оригинальное. А шаблонного как раз полно.

Данную задачу можно решить разными подходами. На вскидку, сразу же пара вариантов:

Вариант 1:
Простая форма и чистым javascript'ом или с помощью jquery биндить события и менять видимость блоков для опросника при нажатии кнопок далее или заполнении всех форм. В конце кнопка, которая отправляет данные на сервер.

Вариант 2:
Использовать Vue JS (или с [BX.Vue](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&CHAPTER_ID=011881&LESSON_PATH=3913.3435.11881)) написать компоненты и красиво, быстро менять информацию. Также в конце кнопка отправлять данные ajax'ом в бэкэнд и сохранять данные.